# About protocol transfer on Messenger

Tags: messenger, livechat, facebook-chatbot

I've a basic question about protocol transfer on Messenger.

How can a community manager takeover a conversation?

I don't want people to click on button to go to the second receiver. I want the community manager blocks the automated answers from the chatbot and go on a live one to one chat via Inbox Messages.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way for a user to take control from the Page Inbox. The only way for the bot to be turned off in a scenario like this is for the bot to use handover protocol to pass thread control to the Page Inbox.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol